# Simple page redirection with add_rewrite_rule

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I need to make simple redirection:
http://my_site/notication-success -> http://my_site/notifications?result=success

For sure, `notifications` page exists.

I wrote the following `init` handler:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('notification-success', 'notifications?result=success', 'top');
});
```

Unfortunately, http://my_site/notification-success produces just 404 error, not redirect.
What's wrong?

UPDATE1:
More correct substitution also doesn't work:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'notification-success', 
        'index.php/?pagename=notifications&result=success', 
        'top');
});
```

UPDATE 2:

regex `^notification\-success$` also doesn't produce expected result

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code - is this a typo from the post? `notifications?result=success` is not wrapped with a single quote. See the syntax highlighting in your post for a hint.

Comment: @Reece: it was just when typing code here

Comment: Do you have more `add_rewrite_rule` in your code?

Comment: @anubhava: No, i's just one rule

Comment: Knock, knock... Does anybody help me?